# locally used font style through @font-face does not show proper font on localhost

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-face, webfonts

I am currently building a leaderboard and wanted to use this font that can be found here
https://fontzone.net/font-download/autumn-regular i will also show what the font is suppose to look like below

[image: Text]

But when i use font face to implement the text does not alter to this style of font as shown here below

[image: Text]

In this example i have the styling for td as well as the tfoot th set to show this font.
I have tried using this with the local() function and url() but both give the same result.
If there's anything i can help assist with giving a clearer understanding please ask in the comments.
Here is the code im using:

```css
 html {
        font-family: "helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif, autumnregular";
      }
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'autumnregular';
        src: url('autumn_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    
    }
    img{
      float: right;
    }
      thead th,
      tfoot th {
       
        font-family: 'autumnregular';
     
      
      }
      
      th {
        letter-spacing: 2px;
      }
      
      td {
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        font-family: 'autumnregular';
     
      }
      
      tbody td {
        text-align: center;
      }
      
      tfoot th {
        text-align: right;
      }
      table {
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 3px solid purple;
      }
      
      thead th:nth-child(1) {
        width: 20%;
      }
      
      thead th:nth-child(2) {
        width: 20%;
      }
      
      thead th:nth-child(3) {
        width: 25%;
      }
      
      thead th:nth-child(4) {
        width: 25%;
      }
      
      th,
      td {
        padding: 10px;
        
      }
      
    thead,
    tfoot {
      background: url(leopardskin.jpg);
      color: white;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
    }
    
    thead th,
    tfoot th,
    tfoot td {
      background: linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
      );
      border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    
    }
    tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color: #3340b8;
    }
    
    tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #959ae4;
    }
    
    
    
    table {
      background-color: #355591;
    }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link
      href="https://fontzone.net/font-download/autumn-regular"
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css" />
    <style>
   </style>
     
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <header class="main-header">
            <table id="myTable">
                <caption>
               
                </caption>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">CHARACTER Icon</th>
                    <th scope="col">Username</th>
                    <th scope="col">Badges</th>
                    <th scope="col">Faction</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row"></th>
                    <td>fighter2</td>
                    <td><img style="display: block;-webkit-user-select: none;" src ="https://i.ibb.co/NSwLYkR/MARISSA-EMBLEM.png" height="50" ></td>
                    <td>Blitz</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row"></th>
                    <td>fighter2</td>
                    <td><img style="display: block;-webkit-user-select: none;" src ="https://i.ibb.co/NSwLYkR/MARISSA-EMBLEM.png" height="50" ></td>
                    <td>Blitz</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row"></th>
                    <td>fighter2</td>
                    <td><img style="display: grid;" src ="https://i.ibb.co/8jK88Y6/MARISSA-EMBLEM111.png" height="50" ><img style="display: grid;" src ="https://i.ibb.co/8jK88Y6/MARISSA-EMBLEM111.png" height="50" ><img style="display: block;-webkit-user-select: none;" src ="https://i.ibb.co/8jK88Y6/MARISSA-EMBLEM111.png" height="50" ></td>
                    <td>Blitz</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/cCxLQCQ/Cammy-icon11.png" height="150" ></th>
                    <td>fighter1</td>
                    <td><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"> <img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"></td>
                    <td>Galaxy</td>
                  </tr> <tr>
                    <th scope="row"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/Jx8mXYC/deejayicon.png" height="120" ></th>
                    <td>KaiRos</td>
                    <td><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"> <img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"></td>
                    <td>Galaxy</td>
                  </tr>
                </tr> <tr>
                  <th scope="row"><img src="https://www.fightersgeneration.com/nx9/char/ultra-sf4-chibi/chunli-ultra-sf4-chibi.png" height="100" width="100"></th>
                  <td>KaiRos</td>
                  <td><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"> <img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"></td>
                  <td>Galaxy</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row"><img src="https://www.fightersgeneration.com/nx9/char/ultra-sf4-chibi/chunli-ultra-sf4-chibi.png" height="100" width="100"></th>
                  <td>KaiRos</td>
                  <td><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"> <img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"></td>
                  <td>Galaxy</td>
                </tr>
                   
                </tbody>
                
              </table>
            </nav>
        </header>        
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Where, exactly, have you stored the font?

Comment: @AHaworth i have it stored here 
C:\Users\juliu\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face for how to use local fonts.